# After installing rails/webpacker, ./bin/webpack-watcher gives me an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

My rails app is currently on `5.0.1`.

I've installed the `rails/webpacker` gem and generated the respective binstubs using the following command: `bin/rails webpacker:install`.

I've also installed `webpack` using `yarn add --dev webpack`.

Now, after running `./bin/webpack-watcher`, I get the following error: `sh: ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js: No such file or directory`.

I admit, I'm brand new to webpack, so I don't know if I'm doing something in error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you run the generator `bundle exec rails generate webpack_rails:install`  ?

Comment: No, I'm not using `webpack-rails` gem (which I think you're referring to). I'm using `rails/webpacker` gem. I used the `bin/rails webpacker:install` command to generate the binstubs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a lot of stuff. From the root of your rails application, open terminal and run:

```
 bin/yarn add --dev webpack webpack-merge webpack-dev-server path-complete-extname babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-latest coffee-loader coffee-script rails-erb-loader glob
```

I'm pretty sure running `bin/rails webpacker:install` to an existing application will also run the above line.

Answer (score 0):

The `webpacker` gem expects your `node_modules`, `package.json`, and `yarn.lock` file to be in the app's `vendor` folder. This will automatically be created for you during `bin/rails webpacker:install` if you have the `yarn` dependency management system installed.

```
cd ./vendor
yarn add --dev webpack
```